# Truth Value of a Series Ambiguous when using While loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question has certainly been asked in many forms before, however, I haven't been able to find one that incorporates multiple series inputs as well as a while loop. Hence my question:

**Without the need for a for-loop ahead of the while loop, is it possible to output a series from this function:**

```
def modify_to_100(first, second):
    combined = first + second

    while combined != 100:
        combined += 1

    return abs(combined)
```

I am passing multiple pandas series to the function. The series are always of the same length.

```
In [132]: first = pd.Series([50, 60, 40])
In [133]: second = pd.Series([20, 10, 40])
In [134]: modify_to_100(first,second)
```

The error I get - which is fairly descriptive and understandable. However, because each element of the Series will require a different number of loops, I am at loss as to the best way to handle this situation.

```
Out [134]: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have tried `a.all()`, as an example, and as expected this causes the loop to go forever. There will never be a time in which all() of the numbers will have 1 added to them and arrive to 100 at the same time.

The others `a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any()` don't seem to apply. Am I misperceiving one of these that might allow for each element of the series to progress individually?

So far everything that I have found suggests that a for-loop is necessary. **I would like to avoid having to go row by row here.**

Desired Output:

```
100, 100, 100
```

Any help, clarification, or efficient way to progress here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears when you try to apply logical relations on a series. You can do this for an element of the series. So use a loop, extract an element from the series, and apply `while` condition element-wise. Hope this helps!

Comment: I ended up having to use a for-loop. In this case I didn't end up modifying the function itself, but just passed elements to it via for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a series with scalar value. combine is a series while 100 is a numeric value.

You can convert series into dataframe and pass into the function.

```
def modify_to_100(df):

    df['new'] = df['first'] + df['second']
    # df['new'] = np.where(df['new']!=100, 100, df['new'])
    while True:
        if all(df['new'].eq(100)):
            break
        df[df['new']<100] = df['new']+1

    return df['new'].values

first = pd.Series([50, 60, 40])
second = pd.Series([20, 10, 40])

print(modify_to_100(pd.DataFrame({'first':first.values, 'second':second.values})))
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this. I am working to adapt to my use case. I particularly need the iterative nature (combined+1) of the while loop. np.where will not work here.

Comment: can you explain in your question what `combine+1` evaluates? As far as I understood it will generate output `71, 71, 81`

Comment: It would evaluate to those numbers on the first iteration, but because of the (while != 100) it would evaluate again. `72, 72, 81` , `73, 73, 82`, and so on. What I would like is for the first two elements to stop after 30 iterations and the third to stop after 20. Thereby arriving to `100` on each element.

Comment: Edited question to be more concise/pythonic with (combined += 1)

Comment: I think this is close. I will work to adapt properly and test. Will let you know what I find.

Comment: `df['new']+1` causes all rows in 'new' to change to 81 and then increment together. Ideally each row would increment independently. The real version of this function is an optimizer - so its looking for where each row is independantly beneath some tolerance. https://aaronschlegel.me/implied-volatility-functions-python.html (See 'newton_vol_call') The more I think about this, and see different ways to do it, the more I think that a for-loop will be necessary to iterate _separately_ over each row. I very much appreciate your help/suggestions though!